# Android ContentResolver creates file with random filename

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to create a GIF using the ContentResolver using this code

```
val fileName = "mygif.gif"

// Add a specific media item.
val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

// Find all video files on the primary external storage device.
val videoCollection =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }

val gifDetails = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
}

resolver.insert(videoCollection, gifDetails)?.let { uri ->
    val os = resolver.openOutputStream(uri)
    // [...] creates GIF with Outputstream
}
```

My file is correctly created, but Android names it like `16118154646.jpg` instead of `mygif.gif`. Neither the name nor the extension is correctly set. How to do this?

Comment: Use `put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/gif")` for the MIME type, inside your `apply {}` lambda.

Comment: Had tried this, and tried again but that does not do the trick unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This code does not work on Android <= 28, but does on Android >= 29.